# Add CharField to the search index in haystack

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack

I use in my django app (1.8), haystack (2.4.1) to search. And I want to be able to serach words with autocomplete (EdgeNgramField) and words when I put only the part of name, for example 'zo-zo on' (this isn't working with EdgeNgramField)

Below I tired added: `text_sec = indexes.CharField(use_template=True)` but this isn't working for me.

Here is my code, but he doesn't works:

```
class EventIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    text_sec = indexes.CharField(use_template=True)
    id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='id')
    get_absolute_url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='get_absolute_url')
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description', null=True)
    is_past = indexes.CharField(model_attr='is_past', default='false')
    date_start = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_start')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup to different fields in your schema to power autocomplete and normal search.
In the following i have defined two fields i.e. one is `text` and other is `content_auto` one which is populated with title from your model.

```
class EventIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')
    text_sec = indexes.CharField(use_template=True)
    id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='id')
    get_absolute_url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='get_absolute_url')
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description', null=True)
    is_past = indexes.CharField(model_attr='is_past', default='false')
    date_start = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_start')
```

When you want to do normal search you should search on text field, for autosuggest on content_auto.

You should read up on docs http://haystacksearch.org/ for more on this,